# Is it possible to disable UAC for a specific USER on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, automation, uac, vsphere

We have the following problem. We want to be able to install software without UAC and then later on switch the user and have UAC enabled. With the help of BrekIT (brekit.com) we then automate an installation process with UAC enabled. 

In order to be able to be flexible we need to have a solution where we can toggle between UAC on and off without user interaction. It's executed in a secured test area so we don't need to worry about possible security risks.

Also worth to note. We use a vSphere Server with many vm's for testing. Perhaps with vmware there might be an alternate easier solution.

Thank you very much!
Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that this is not possible. Imagine the security implications: All malware has to do is temporarily disable UAC, install the payload, and enable it again. Sorry.

Comment: That's true, but for automated testing environments this is a bumer. Thanks for the answer! Just wanted to make sure I am not missing a thing.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's for an automated testing environment. If UAC could be bypassed that easily, it would be pointless. IMO UAC is a very good technology that was introduced into the Windows ecosystem. It is absolutely imperative that we break the "everybody is an admin" mindset.

Comment: Well it is possible to disable UAC for all Users with group policies. Why is it not possible to disable it for one? I don't see a higher risk there. Actually for me it sounds like a feature which would make sense in some cases and wouldn't be a security breach.

Comment: [Side note to drive-by downvoter] Not liking the answer doesn't change the fact that it is the answer.